# protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to implement Guardian into my API and perform a login through it to get JWT back. The tutorial I'm looking at is [here](http://hassox.github.io/elixir/guardian/2015/06/29/simple-email-password-authentication.html). The problem is implementing the login using a User Model similar to what they're using in the example. The Model code looks like:

```
defmodule PushflightServer.User do
  use PushflightServer.Web, :model

use Ecto.Repo
import Ecto.Query
  alias PushflightServer.Repo

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :encrypted_password, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :verify_token, :string
    field :verify_date, Ecto.DateTime

    timestamps
  end

  def from_email(nil), do: { :error, :not_found }
  def from_email(email) do
    IO.write("Before email")
    IO.inspect(email)
    Repo.one(User, email: email)
  end
```

If I call the from_email either from within Phoenix or straight in **iex -S mix**, I get the following error:

*user = PushflightServer.User.from_email("rob@json.com")*

> ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for User, the given module does not exist
>       (ecto) lib/ecto/queryable.ex:33: Ecto.Queryable.Atom.to_query/1
>       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:90: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
>       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:15: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
>       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:44: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.one/4

I must be missing something simple, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about why this is happening. The insert of the data using the Repo worked fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

You need to fully namespace `User` as `PushflightServer.User` or you can use the shortcut `__MODULE__`

Answer (score 3):

you should reference the modules with namespaces

```
  def from_email(email) do
    PushflightServer.one(PushflightServer.User, email: email)
  end
```